# Best approach to use when values are dynamically created?

Tags: webdriver, junit

I'm looking for some advice on how to select a WebElement.
When I click a button that creates a new 'page', the given value is dynamic, in that it is totally random and not sequential. I would expect it to follow something like: page 1 = 0, page 2 = 1, page 3 = 2, etc.

By default I begin with a page. Although when I trigger a button to create new pages the values appear as follows:

```
<select class="j-currentPage f-feature-A" name="currentPage">  <option value="c3">New Page</option>  <option value="c277">New Page 2</option>  <option value="c383">New Page 3</option>  <option selected="" value="c461">New Page 4</option>  </select>
```

So when I attempt to use the following:

```
 List<WebElement> option = chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    option.get(0).click();
    option.get(1).click();
    option.get(0).click();
```

It's obviously failing as the values are c277, c346 etc etc, and there is no way of knowing what the values will be in a new session as they will always be different.

The stacktrace is throwing a `StaleElementReferenceException` because its not in the DOM.

How can I select each page when the values are completely random?

I'm using Webdriver and JUnit4.

**EDIT**

Test method: to create some new pages.

```
@Test
public void createANewPage(){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(chrome, 60);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select.j-currentPage.f-feature-A[name=\"currentPage\"]")));

    WebElement newPage = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.j-addViewBtn.ss-layers"));
    newPage.click();

    List<WebElement> option = chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    option.get(1).click();

    option.get(0).click();
}
```

Then a few tests later I want to call back the created page(s)

```
@Test
public void goToPage(){

    new WebDriverWait(chrome, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select.j-currentPage.f-feature-A[name=\"currentPage\"]")));
    List<WebElement> option = chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    option.get(0).click();
    option.get(1).click();
    option.get(0).click();
}
```

I receive a `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException` at the point of the third `option.get(0).click();`

However I feel as though I'm approaching this the wrong way as the values are dynamically created `<option value="c3">New Page</option>

<option value="c207">New Page 2</option>

<option value="c288">New Page 3</option>

<option selected="" value="c366">New Page 4</option>`

Answer (score 2):

If the element you are interacting with is being replaced in the DOM, which appears to be the case since you're getting a stale element exception, you'll need to find the element again rather than re-using the existing one.  So for example, you would do this:

```
chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option")).get(0).click();
chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option")).get(1).click();
chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option")).get(0).click();
```

Another option would be to put it in a try/catch block and refresh only if an exception is caught.  I found a good example of a generic method of waiting for all of your elements here: https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5112655

Whether the element is being generated dynamically or not is really kind of irrelevant, this happens any time an element is removed from the DOM and then re-added (including if you navigate to a new page and then back to the original page).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use xpath. And here I see two ways: 1) function `contains(text(),'New Page')` -- it searches by partial text, 2) function `text()='New page \\d+'` -- it searches every text 'New pages ' followed by numbers (using regex). Doing this allows you to avoid verifying dynamic values of elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement selectButton = driver.findElement(By.name("currentPage"));
List<WebElement> list_selectButton = selectButton.findElements(By.tagName("option"));


List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); {List stores the dynamic values of every option tag under select menu]


for(int i=0; i< list_selectButton-1; i++){

list.add(list_selectButton.get(i).getAttribute("value"));

}

//Now retrieve list contents and you can perform your tasks.
```

But, in order to click on every option element in your above scenario, I don't think you need to find the dynamic value, instead you can do something like this below ->

```
selectButton.click() // This will ensure that the option elements under it is now visible in the DOM and then you continue to click the option elements.

Thread.sleep(2000) // Delay because sometimes option elements will not be visible immediately, need to wait for sometime. You can add wait statements here instead.

list_selectButton.get(0).click
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments @user3164290 although your code does not seem to work. For instance, the diamonds after the `ArrayList` are not compatible with my language type. There is also another incompatible type with `list_selectButton-1` as this seems to require a Boolean. Im interested to see how the ArrayList can capture the values. Any further explanation would be great. Thanks in advance.
Also, the `getAttribute("value"));` method in the  cannot be resolved.

Comment: 1. Can you tell me which language are you using?

Comment: Java with JUnit 4.11 as the execution framework.